# get exeption when try to update foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

im learning now mysql and jdbc and i got home work im trying to add a foreign key and i cant understant what is this exeption this is my code please if someone can explain me what the problem it will realy help me

```
package jdbc;

import java.sql.*;

public class JDBC_HW {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

try (Connection connection = DriverManager
        .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/newdatabase", "root", "admin")) {
    try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
        String newTable = "CREATE TABLE  jb_student (id int not null auto_increment, name varchar(500), grade int, PRIMARY key(id));";
        statement.executeUpdate(newTable);

    }
    String insertStudents = "INSERT INTO newdatabase.jb_student "
            + "( name, grade)"
            + " VALUES( ?, ?);";
    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertStudents)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "student" + i);
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, i * 100);

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        }
    }

    String printTable = "select * from newdatabase.jb_student";

    try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(printTable);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.print(resultSet.getInt(1));
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(resultSet.getString(2));
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.println(resultSet.getInt(3));
        }
    }

    String update = "UPDATE jb_student SET name = 'nikita', grade = 100 where id = 1;";

    try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
        int countUpdates = statement.executeUpdate(update);
        System.out.println("updated rows : " + countUpdates);
    }

    String searchByName1 = "select * from jb_student where name like '%1';";

    try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(searchByName1);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.print(resultSet.getInt(1));
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(resultSet.getString(2));
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.println(resultSet.getInt(3));
        }
    }


    String newTable = "CREATE TABLE  jb_courses (id int not null auto_increment, name varchar(500), PRIMARY key(id));";
    try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
        statement.executeUpdate(newTable);
    }

    String insertCourses = "INSERT INTO newdatabase.jb_courses "
            + "(name)"
            + " VALUES(?);";

    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertCourses)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "course" + " " + i);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }
    }

    String addColumn = "ALTER TABLE jb_student ADD COLUMN course_id int not null AFTER id;";

    try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
        statement.executeUpdate(addColumn);
    }

    String addFk = "ALTER TABLE jb_student add FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES jb_courses (id);";

    try(Statement statement = connection.createStatement()){
        statement.executeUpdate(addFk);
    }

    



} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


}
}
```

im sitting on this long time and cant resolve this exeption i tryied everithing i could think of
and im still getting this exeption :

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`newdatabase`.`#sql-12f0_21`, CONSTRAINT `jb_student_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`course_id`) REFERENCES `jb_courses` (`id`))
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1333)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2106)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1243)
at jdbc.JDBC_HW.main(JDBC_HW.java:92)
```

im braking my head on this thank you for helping

Comment: What this means is that you are trying to add a row with a `course_id` that is not in the `jb_courses` table. There could be a lot of reasons for that, so the first step in debugging is to look at the exact query that was executed, and see what the value for `course_id` was.

Comment: thank you very much the problem was that i wrote : String addColumn = "ALTER TABLE jb_student ADD COLUMN course_id int not null AFTER id;"; "course_id not null" , but why this is a problem i cant understant when i delete the not null its worked